# How to inject opentelemetry agent with dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, fastapi, open-telemetry

I'm using opentelemtry with a fastapi application using an agent.
To inject that agent i used to run this command locally

`OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES=service.name=waves-datahandler OTEL_PYTHON_EXCLUDED_URLS="/metrics" OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT="http://0.0.0.0:4317" opentelemetry-instrument python3 main.py` 
but when it comes to containerizing the application using docker i get stuck.

i tried to add env variables like this:

`ENV OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES=service.name=waves-datahandler ENV OTEL_PYTHON_EXCLUDED_URLS="/metrics" ENV OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT="http://0.0.0.0:4317"` 
but when it comes to the command i used this :

`CMD ["main.py"] ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "-m", "opentelemetry-instrument", "python3", "main.py"]` 
but within this case it tells me opentelemetry-instrument is not find.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look opentelemetry-python specific. [This](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python-contrib/tree/main/opentelemetry-instrumentation) is the python package that provides the `opentelemetry-instrument` command, make sure your container has access to it in order to be able to run that command.